# PHP foreach notworking

Tags: php, foreach

My XML looks like this:

```
                  [image] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [foto_0] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339643.JPG
                                [foto_1] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339933.JPG
                                [foto_2] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339384.JPG
                                [foto_3] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339853.JPG
                                [foto_4] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339334.JPG
                                [foto_5] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339229.JPG
                                [foto_6] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339487.JPG
                                [foto_7] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339570.JPG
                                [foto_8] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339096.JPG
                                [foto_9] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339516.JPG
                                [foto_10] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339911.JPG
                                [foto_11] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339201.JPG
                                [foto_12] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339042.JPG
                                [foto_13] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339307.JPG
                                [foto_14] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339754.JPG
                                [foto_15] => http://pics.auto-commerce.eu/ac1358/foto/1421058132339305.JPG
                            )
```

Now i want each picture to inserted into the database. Code for saving is working fine. But the foreach don't work. Who want to help me?

Foreach code:

```
foreach($car->image as $photourl){ *DB code* }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does it not work? What happens? Do you get an error? We need more information.

Comment: So what particular bit isn't working? The `for` bit? the `each` bit? or the `*DB code*` bit?

Comment: Try `foreach($car->image as $photourl){ var_dump($photourl); }` to see a little more info.

Comment: Sure like to see what that `*DB code*` is.

Comment: That's not what XML looks like!

Comment: you'll have to address it as $photourl->foto_1 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach($car->image->children() as $photourl){
    echo "Key: " . $photourl->getName() . "<br>";
    echo "Value: " . trim((string)$photourl) . "<br>";
}
```